# From dataFrame to list with TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I would like to create a list that looks like this at the end:

```
[
    {'name': 'Chrome', 'y': 550},
    {'name': 'IE', 'y': 203},
]
```

my data frame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CATEGORY":["Chrome","IE","FireFox","Safari","Opera","QQ"],"Users":[550,203,25,305,15,132]})
```

and in order to acheive this I'm trying something like this:

```
list(map(lambda row: {'name': df[row['CATEGORY']], 'y': row['Users']}, df))
```

but the result I get is: **TypeError: string indices must be integers**

Can anyone point out (1) what am I doing wrong and (2) how to fix it?

Comment: Do you really want to do it this way or would you be fine with an inbuilt method to do just that? About your error: `df[row['CATEGORY']]` is invalid. See the indexing documentation at [`df.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`df.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.columns = ['name', 'y'] # change the column names to the ones that you want
df.to_dict('records') # this returns a list of dictionaries for each row

[{'name': 'Chrome', 'y': 550},
{'name': 'IE', 'y': 203},
 {'name': 'FireFox', 'y': 25},
 {'name': 'Safari', 'y': 305},
 {'name': 'Opera', 'y': 15},
 {'name': 'QQ', 'y': 132}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` so as to access columns. As you go, you need to construct your dictionary.

```
list(df.apply(lambda x: {'name': x['CATEGORY'], 'y': x['Users']}, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Chrome', 'y': 550},
 {'name': 'IE', 'y': 203},
 {'name': 'FireFox', 'y': 25},
 {'name': 'Safari', 'y': 305},
 {'name': 'Opera', 'y': 15},
 {'name': 'QQ', 'y': 132}]
```

Thank fixes your approach. The **ideal** way however, would be to use [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) as below:

```
df.rename(columns={'CATEGORY': 'name', 'Users': 'y'}).to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Chrome', 'y': 550},
 {'name': 'IE', 'y': 203},
 {'name': 'FireFox', 'y': 25},
 {'name': 'Safari', 'y': 305},
 {'name': 'Opera', 'y': 15},
 {'name': 'QQ', 'y': 132}]
```

This way your original `df` would be unaffected as well.

Comment: @adhg, glad, I could help. Consider accepting the answer.